# Multilayer perceptron neural network has 10% accuracy

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am using the CIFAR-10 dataset to train my neural network and I am getting a score of around `0.10`, which is as if my neural network is just guessing (1/10 odds of a right answer), the CIFAR-10 has 32x32 images of 10 types of things (automobiles, planes, cats, dogs, etc.). I suspect something is wrong with my code.

By the way, it is not an issue with the file unpickling

Please help me!!

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import numpy as np
import time

labels = ["airplane", "automobile", "bird", "cat", "deer", "dog", "frog", "horse", "ship", "truck"]

def unpickle(f):
    import cPickle
    fo = open(f, "rb")
    dict = cPickle.load(fo)
    fo.close()
    return dict

def setup_mlp(unpickled_data):
    new_mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=3072, solver='sgd', batch_size=1000, max_iter=500, random_state=1, learning_rate_init=0.01)
    return new_mlp
#hidden_layer_sizes is the number of neurons in a layer. In this case I have one hidden layer & 3072 neurons in that layer
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unpickled_batch = unpickle("./data_batch_1")
    print int(unpickled_batch["data"].shape[0])
    #time.sleep(1000)
    X_train = unpickled_batch["data"][:1000]
    Y_train = unpickled_batch["labels"][:1000]
    print "Decoded batch, now training\n"
    mlp = setup_mlp(unpickled_batch)
    mlp.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    print "Score=" + str(mlp.score(X_train, Y_train))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem yesterday, so maybe this could help you.

MLPClassifier works fine on Cifar-10 if you standardize the dataset i.e. 
add

`from sklearn import preprocessing
X_train = preprocessing.scale(X_train)`

after loading the data.

But this is not enough since your test set is the same as training set and you will end up with Score=1.0 and with no information of new images prediction.

To fix this you can load 'test_batch' from cifar-10 files or split unpickled_batch["data"] and unpickled_batch["labels"] to train i test datasets.

After that you should get score about 0.3, depending on the size of test set.